# How to create a collection specific search index in Atlas mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I am trying to create a collection specific search index in the atlas MongoDB but not able to find a way.

Found this documentation:
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/atlas-search/#atlas-search-api-ref

but the API they mentioned will create indexed on cluster level

```
/groups/{GROUP-ID}/clusters/{CLUSTER-NAME}/fts/indexes/
```

Can someone guide me on how I will create a collection specific search index via script?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [api endpoint](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/fts-indexes-create-one/) you must provide the collection name.